# Iin KonvaJS, how to batch resize all items in a group porportionally?

Tags: javascript, konvajs

In KonvaJS it is possible to rotate all elements in a group like:

(`this` refers to the group object)

```
this.rotation('30'); // rotates all elements inside the group by 30°
```

Now If I try to resize the width/height it won't work.

```
 // trying to set the group width to 300px and make the grouped items inside increase proportionally.

this.width(300);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it:

```
this.scale({x: '1.1', y: '1.1'});
```

In this case **1.1** means 10% larger. It affects all elements in group.